# How to implement a login in Android using Volley?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I have a LoginActitvity with two textfields for the username and password and a login-button. When the user presses the button, the app starts an async task. The async task implements my VolleyHandler. It checks if the login parameters are correct and fetches some user data (using volley and json). While doing this, a ProgressDialog appears. When the async task is finished, it starts an intent to the MainActivity in the onPostExecute method.

Now to my question: Is it a good idea to make volley-requests in the async task, or do you have a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Volley handles http calls asynchronously already. Why would you put in in an AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use asynctask. Volley care about it. You can use callback for work with data and ui.
Looks like this:

```
public class LoginActivity extends SinglePaneActivity implements DownloadCallback {

//...


public void sendRequest(){
  Downloader download = new Download(this);
  downloader.download(userName, password);
  progresbar.show();
}

public void requestFinish(){
 progersbar.dismis();
 //... continue
  }
}
```

callback:

```
public interface DownloadCallback {
    void requestFinish(); 
}
```

in class downloader

```
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
DownloadCallback mcallback;

public void Downloader(DownloadCallback callback){
   mCallback = callback;
   requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
   initVolleyListeners();
}

private void initVolleyListeners() {

    mSuccessListener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
           mCallback.requestFinish();
        }
    };

    mErrorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             mCallback.requestFinish();
        }
    };

public void download(String user, String pass){
     JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, createJson(user, pass), mSuccessListener , mErrorListener ) {
        //header for send JSON to server
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };

   requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest );
}
```

And one point. Don't send user name in json. You send it as param in header. Use this `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and set up pass an username as  params in header.

**Update:**
Now It will work. Sorry I wrote it in a hurry.
[Article about how callback work](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077462/learn-java/java-tip-10--implement-callback-routines-in-java.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some trouble with the line "requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext, DownloadCallback callback);" - it says "cannot resolve symbol callback". Can you help me please?